# A Question Regarding Euler's Phi Function and Composite $N$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, totient-function, open-problem

Let $N$ be a composite number.

Do we know any necessary conditions on $N$ that will potentially allow $\phi(N) \mid N - 1$?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. FYI, see [Lehmer's totient problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer%27s_totient_problem). In the "Properties" section, several properties about this which have been proven about it are listed.

Comment: It can easily be shown that such a number must be a Carmichael number. More details in the already posted link.